# Saving files to a Mac Computer

Tags: macos, finder, file

I'm trying to save a file to a folder. I keep getting an popup that says I do not have permission to save files to a location

Comment: Which folder and what are its permissions?

Answer (score 1):

> ## Set permissions for items on your Mac
>
> Permission settings determine who can view and alter files on the
>   computer. Permissions are an important factor on OS X and other *nix
>   systems and defines the way the system handles users, files and
>   devices.
>
> #### Assign permissions to users and groups
>
> 1. Select a disk, folder, or file, then choose File > Get Info.
> 2. If the information in Sharing & Permissions isn’t visible, click the disclosure triangle.
> 3. If necessary, click the lock icon to unlock it, then enter an administrator name and password.
> 4. Click a user or group in the Name column, then choose a privilege setting from the pop-up menu.
>
>    - Read & Write: Allows a user to open the item and change it.
>    - Read Only: Allows a user to open the item, but not change its contents.
>    - Write Only: Makes a folder into a drop box. Users can copy items to the drop box, but can’t open it. Only the owner of the drop box can
>        open it.
>    - No Access: Blocks all access to the item.

*Shamelessly copied from: [OS X Yosemite: Set permissions for items on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18894?locale=en_US)*

Another useful read: [Understanding UNIX permissions and chmod](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml)